# jQuery - click event not being added to every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, each

I have a snippet of jQuery code that adds items to an unordered list when a submit button is clicked. Part of what's added to the list is an "X" button to delete the item from the list. I'm using the each() function to add a click event to every element that gets added to the list, yet it's only attaching to the first element.

Oddly enough, if that event gets fired, and the submit button is clicked again, the next element to be added to the list gets the click event.

Here's the snippet of code:

```
$("#addTask").click(function() {
  if ($("#toDoList").val().trim() != "") {
    $("ul.list-group").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + $("#toDoList").val()
        + "         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' id='removeButton'></span></li>");
    $("#toDoList").val("");
  };
  $.each($("#removeButton"), function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems that you're using the same ID multiple times. IDs must be unique. Consider using a class instead.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. And when you fix that, use event delegation to bind the click for the remove icon, don't use `.each()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, IDs **must** be unique, so you need to change `removeButton` from an ID to a class. Then since you are adding the remove buttons dynamically, you need to add the click handler using .on()'s event delegation syntax. This would be accomplished with:

```
$("#addTask").click(function () {
    $("ul").append("<li class='list-group-item'>task <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove removeButton'>X</span></li>");
})
$('ul').on('click', '.removeButton', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wufcmthn/)**